# Transfer App license to another SharePoint server

Tags: sharepoint-server, app, licensing

On a test SP server which has a installed SharePoint 2013 Foundation we have installed an App from SP Store. My issue now is to transfer the App license from this server to another SharePoint 2013 server. I asked the developers from this App (Ardevia Rich Forms) if its possible to transfer the license from one server to another. They said that we need to set or change the deployment ID for this App and they gave me these links https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn449108.aspx#bk_details and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219471.aspx.

Could someone explain me the steps how to successfully transfer license from one SharePoint to another since it's my first time in doing this.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

First get your DeploymentId from the old farm:

```
(Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ?{$_.TypeName -eq "App Management Service Application Proxy"}).GetDeploymentId().ToString()
```

Then, on the new farm, set it:

```
$sa = Get-SPServiceApplication | ?{$_.TypeName -eq "App Management Service Application"}
Set-SPAppManagementDeploymentId -DeploymentId "<GUID From Previous Output>" -AppManagementServiceApplication $sa
```

Comment: On the new farm we already have 2 licenses (for 2 users) from the same App. If we use these Power Shell commands will it be added as a third license? We need to know this because the farm is already being used for our clients.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: This changes the DeploymentId of the farm. You'll lose all existing licenses on the 'new' farm. I'd suggest working something out in terms of payment with the vendor directly, perhaps a refund or something along those lines.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what we looked for. Best regards.